# Persist an object with unknow type using ServiceStack.OrmLite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I want to write a service method using [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/) (c#) and [ServiceStack.OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) to save the dynamic objects, sent by client (in parameter), in a SQL Database. Also, this method will first create the table in database for this dynamic object. Service will be unable to recognize the class type of the object to be persisted as it will only be defined on client side.

I have explored OrmLite a bit and found that it has [DatabaseTableConfig and DatabaseFieldConfig](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_5.html#Class-Configuration) classes to persist an object with unknown type. Unfortunately I am unable to find these classes in [ServiceStack.OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) library.

Any help in the coding strategy?

Comment: Would it not be best to serialize the object to JSON and then store the JSON as text in the database? Then simply return that JSON to the client? Then your service would never have to worry about the type of data at all?

Comment: Also if the Service doesn't know the type of object it is being sent, how will it know what table it's building for the storage of this dynamic object? So could one request be for example `{ name: "John Smith", age: 27 }` and another be `{ city: "Paris", sport: "Tennis", colour: "blue" }`? This sort of dynamic object is typically handled by NoSQL solutions. It be great if you could provide some more insight as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Actually i am trying to avoid to persist JSON because I want to be able to execute SQL queries for filtering and organizing the result sets. Client can send request to fetch data with filters in a key-value pair collection e.g column name string along with operator like eq, noteq, gt, lt etc. Actually there would be many clients using this service having a separate DB on server and each client would have different model/schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java OrmLite and the ServiceStack.OrmLite are not the same and as such the classes you refer to do not exist in ServiceStack.OrmLite.

> Service will be unable to recognize the class type of the object to be persisted

As you are creating dynamic objects which you can't type, then an ORM (Object-relational mapping) is probably not the way to go, as ORM is all about using **typed** data.

The best approach would be to build the SQL queries yourself, and use a `SqlCommand`.